# OnEdit need to send emails from a column

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, google-sheets

When in column O cell is mentioned "Shipped" I want to send emails in column C (with corresponding row)

Need support to get this script right

```
function sendEmail(e) {
    var thisSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (thisSheet.getName() !== 'CRM' || e.range.columnStart !== 15 || e.range.rowStart == 1 || e.value !== 'Shipped') return;
    var body, headers = thisSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 6)
        .getValues()[0],
        thisRow = thisSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 6)
        .getValues()[0],
        recipientsEMail = (thisSheet.getRange.columnStart !==3 || e.range.rowStart ==1)
        .getValues()[0],
        recipients = recipientsEMail,
        subject = "Your Vehicle is shipped " + e.source.getName(),
        body = "",
        i = 0;
    while (i < 6) {
        body += headers[i] +' - ' + thisRow[i] +'\n';
        i++;
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
}
```

[My sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZjmC3xz2dV3MhUlH-j7Kc3bexnzqFAKnbWAyxzThg_U/edit#gid=1073970174)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
var thisSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (thisSheet.getName() !== 'CRM' || e.range.columnStart !== 15 || e.range.rowStart == 1 || e.value !== 'Shipped') return;
var body, headers = thisSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 15)
    .getValues()[0],
    thisRow = thisSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 15)
    .getValues()[0];
    var recipients = thisRow[2];
    var subject = "Your Vehicle is shipped " + e.source.getName(),
    body = "Dear Customer,\n\nYour vehicle has been shipped from Japan";


MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
}
```

You didn't say how much columns you need to use to construct the body of the email but that can be easily changed if you increase the number in the while loop.

Comment: Thanks JPV, it works, I wish to send customized message without the column content in the email body. Something like this " Dear Customer, Your vehicle has been shipped from Japan"

Comment: Edited my response to reflect your latest requirement.