# How do I send an automated email to a specific person, depending on task status, using an aux sheet to store emails?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Gory title but I couldn't find a way of being clearer.

I have no experience with coding and I was wondering if doing something like what I'm about to explain would be possible.

[This is my example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kEVysROdWZjrdHYeu7-peTLTemm42m6GDyeb1JW48v4/edit?usp=sharing):

What I'm looking to do is to have automated emails sent out to the person assigned to the task if the task status is set to urgent, while referencing people by names and having an auxiliary sheet with all the names and corresponding emails.

I've browsed around and found some similar questions which I unfortunately had no success in adapting. The one thing I got is that I need to setup an onEdit trigger, which I've done, but I'm completely clueless from here on out.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I don't have a clue where to start.

Looking forward to hearing your advice.
Thanks and stay safe in these crazy times!

Comment: Welcome. Short answer: This is totally possible. You are right about onEdit - would you please edit your answer to include the code that you've written. FWIW, I'd probably turn the "Responsible" field into a dropdown (source the names from AUX) so that there is no chance of a typo. Longer answer: there are lots of precedents about, so this shouldn't be too painless for you.

Comment: Have a look at [OnEdit need to send emails from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966785/1330560). This is a decent example of the kind of script that you will need.

Comment: Hey, Ted, and thank you! I don't really have any code put together. I've browsed around and found a couple of similar questions but my lack of experience only allows me to copy paste stuff here and there and if it works, it works. If it doesn't work, I'm not exactly able to tell why. I'll give the source you sent a look, for sure, and try to adapt to my solution. I'll most likely come back with more questions if you're up to answer them. Thanks again and have a great evening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a funny exercise. I tried to make the script as clean and reusable as possible for others to be able to adapt it to their needs.

**Usage**

1. Open spreadsheet you want to add script to.
2. Open Script Editor: `Tools / Script editor`.
3. Add the code. It can be configured by adjusting variables in the top:

```js
var trackerSheetName = 'Tracker 1'
var trackerSheetStatusColumnIndex = 2
var trackerSheetNameColumnIndex = 4
var triggeringStatusValue = 'Urgent'

var peopleSheetName = 'AUX'
var peopleSheetNameColumnIndex = 1
var peopleSheetEmailColumnIndex = 2

var emailSubject = 'We need your attention'
var emailBody = 'It is urgent'

function checkStatusUpdate(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()

  // skip if different sheet edited
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== trackerSheetName) {
    return
  }

  var editedRange = e.range

  // skip if not a single cell edit
  if (editedRange.columnStart !== editedRange.columnEnd || editedRange.rowStart !== editedRange.rowEnd) {
    return
  }

  // skip if edited cell is not from Status column
  if (editedRange.columnStart !== trackerSheetStatusColumnIndex) {
    return
  }

  // skip if Status changed to something other than we're looking for
  if (e.value !== triggeringStatusValue) {
    return
  }

  var assigneeName = activeSheet.getRange(editedRange.rowStart, trackerSheetNameColumnIndex, 1, 1).getValue()

  var peopleSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(peopleSheetName)
  var people = peopleSheet.getRange(2, 1, peopleSheet.getMaxRows(), peopleSheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues()

  // filter out empty rows
  people.filter(function (person) {
    return person[peopleSheetNameColumnIndex - 1] && person[peopleSheetEmailColumnIndex - 1]
  }).forEach(function (person) {
    if (person[peopleSheetNameColumnIndex - 1] === assigneeName) {
      var email = person[peopleSheetEmailColumnIndex - 1]

      MailApp.sendEmail(email, emailSubject, emailBody)
    }
  })
}
```

4. Save the code in editor.
5. Open Installable Triggers page: `Edit / Current project's triggers`.
6. Create a new trigger. Set `Event Type` to `On edit`. Keep other options default.
7. Save the Trigger and confirm granting the script permissions to access spreadsheets and send email on your behalf.
8. Go back to your spreadsheet and try changing status in `Tracker 1` tab for any of the rows. Corresponding recipient should receive an email shortly.

Comment: Hey, Max! I wasn't expecting the full answer to be here when I woke up but this works brilliantly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

You will need to create an installable trigger for onMyEdit function.  The dialog will help you to design you email by giving you an html format to display it.  When you're ready just comment out the dialog and remove the `//` from in front of the GmailApp.sendEdmail() line.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Tracker") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.value=='Urgent') {
      //e.source.toast('flag1');
      const title=e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue();
      const desc=e.range.offset(0,1).getValue();
      const comm=e.range.offset(0,3).getValue();
      if(title && desc) {
        var html=Utilities.formatString('<br />Task Title:%s<br />Desc:%s<br />Comments:%s',title,desc,comm?comm:"No Additional Comments");
        //GmailApp.sendEmail(e.range.offset(0,2).getValue(), "Urgent Message from Tracker", '',{htmlBody:html});
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(600), 'Tracker Message');
        e.source.toast('Email Sent');
      }else{
        e.source.toast('Missing Inputs');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[GmailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))